# Determine the value of a variable present in dataset A but not in dataset B (which is exactly the same as dataset A except for this variable)

Tags: r, database, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have two datasets that are the same except for one variable. For example, as demonstrated below, I have two datasets called `boys_miss` and `boys_miss2`. `boys_miss2` has an extra binary variable (called type) that `boys_miss` doesn't. So I would like to determine the `type` variable in `boys_miss` using the observed variables in both datasets. I am not sure what would be the best way to do this. Any solutions or suggestions would greatly appreciated.

```
# loads relevant packages using the pacman package
pacman::p_load(
  mice)        # for boys dataset


# set seed
set.seed(2347723) 


# generate a samall sample of the boys dataset
boys_miss <- sample(head(boys,100))

# create other dataset that has out variable of interest
boys_miss2 <- boys_miss[sample(1:nrow(boys_miss)), ] 

# create the variable of interest
boys_miss2$type <- as.factor(sample(c("runner", "swimmer"), 
                           size = nrow(boys_miss2), 
                           replace = TRUE, 
                           prob = c(.76, .24)))




# Goal here is to replicate type variable in `boys_miss` dataset using the values the matching 
# in `boys_miss` and `boys_miss2`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `match` on a `paste`ed string from both columns, use the index to return the corresponding 'type' values

```
boys_miss$type <- boys_miss2$type[match(do.call(paste, boys_miss), 
      do.call(paste, boys_miss2[-ncol(boys_miss2)]))]
```

Comment: This works on the dataset above, but not for large dataset consisting of 18,000 rows. Not sure what would be different here aside from the number of rows and columns.